# Searching for documents within a zip file - sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

Is it possible for SharePoint to return files bases on a search which are stored within a zip file? Ive tested it with a Windows compressed file and the search returned nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, only the file is crawled. You can add a ZIP iFilter and register it with SharePoint if you want to crawl the contents.

http://ifiltershop.com/zipfilter.html